# How to rearrange second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can i accomplish this?

The temperature, $T (=T(X))$, of a fin of perimeter P with cross-sectional area is given by

$$ \frac{d^2 T}{dx^2 }- \frac{hP}{kA} T=0$$

where h is the convection heat transfer coefficient, $k$ is the thermal conductivity and $x$ is the distance along the fin. Find an expression for $T$ in terms of $k$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables

Comment: hint: set $\frac{hP}{kA} = \lambda^2$ then you have an equation that looks like $$\frac{d^2 T}{dx^2} - \lambda^2 T = 0$$ which should be recognizable as a differential equation.

Comment: @MattiP. That doesn't work on second order equations